# Remove duplicate values on an array with a condition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I want to remove some duplicate values on an array, but there is a condition that the script has to ignore the array that contains a specific word.

Below code is adapted from [**PHP: in_array**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php).

```
$array = array( 'STK0000100001',
                'STK0000100002',
                'STK0000100001',           //--> This should be remove
                'STK0000100001-XXXX',      //--> This should be ignored
                'STK0000100001-XXXX' );    //--> This should be ignored

$ignore_values = array('-XXXX');

if(make_unique($array, $ignore_values) > 0) {
    //ERROR HERE
}
```

The function to make the array unique is:

```
function make_unique($array, $ignore) {
    $i = 0;
    while($values = each($array))  {
        if(!in_array($values[1], $ignore)) {
            $dupes = array_keys($array, $values[1]);
            unset($dupes[0]);
            foreach($dupes as $rmv) {
                $i++;
            }            
        }
    }
    return $i;
}
```

I have tried to use `if(!in_array(str_split($values[1]), $ignore)) ...` but it just the same.

The array should become like:

```
STK0000100001
STK0000100002
STK0000100001-XXXX
STK0000100001-XXXX
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, just remove the `print_r();` inside the function when using in production

```
if(make_unique($array, $ignore_values) > 0) {
    //ERROR HERE
}

function make_unique($array, $ignore)  {
    $array_hold = $array;
    $ignore_val = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        foreach($ignore as $ign) {
            if(strpos($arr, $ign)) { 
                 array_push( $ignore_val, $arr);
                 unset($array_hold[$i]);
                 break;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $unique_one = (array_unique($array_hold));
    $unique_one = array_merge($unique_one,$ignore_val);
    print_r($unique_one);

    return count($array) - count($unique_one);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for `>= PHP 5.3`.

```
$res = array_reduce($array, function ($res, $val) use ($ignore_values) { 
    $can_ignore = false;
    foreach ($ignore_values as $ignore_val) {
      if (substr($val, 0 - strlen($ignore_val)) == $ignore_val) {
        $can_ignore = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if ( $can_ignore || ! in_array($val, $res)) {
      $res[] = $val;
    }
    return $res;

  }, array()
);
```

Otherwise

```
$num_of_duplicates = 0;
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $val) { 
  $can_ignore = false;
  foreach ($ignore_values as $ignore_val) {
    if (substr($val, 0 - strlen($ignore_val)) == $ignore_val) {
      $num_of_duplicates++;
      $can_ignore = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( $can_ignore || ! in_array($val, $res)) {
    $res[] = $val;
  }
}
```

Edit: Added `duplicate count` to the second snippet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. It solved my problem but it's not returning any counting value to identify if there was some value removed from the array. And btw I already have the answer. Thanks again! :)